# T-statistics calculated from bootstrapped standard error

Tags: python, t-test, standard-error

May I ask does anyone know if there is a library for calculating t-statistics based on bootstrapped standard error instead of regular standard error in python? I have searched for so long but it seems there isn't anyone... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Software recommendations are unfortunately offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) can be performed in Python using the `bootstrapped` package ([GitHub](https://github.com/facebookincubator/bootstrapped), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/bootstrapped/)):

```
import numpy as np
import bootstrapped.bootstrap as bs
import bootstrapped.stats_functions as bs_stats

mean = 100
stdev = 10

population = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=stdev, size=50000)

# take 1k 'samples' from the larger population
samples = population[:1000]

print(bs.bootstrap(samples, stat_func=bs_stats.mean))
>> 100.08  (99.46, 100.69)

print(bs.bootstrap(samples, stat_func=bs_stats.std))
>> 9.49  (9.92, 10.36)
```